# How to know the rope needed to wrap a pipe based on the diameter of a pipe

Tags: geometry

How to know the rope needed to wrap a pipe based on the diameter of a pipe and length.

Knowing that the tube is 2.80meters and has a diameter of 20cm. How many meters of rope with a thickness of 1cm are needed to completely wrap the pipe?

From what I understand, the length of a winding is described as:

[image: formula]

So to obtain the total length, i need multiply by the number of windings, which is obtained by dividing the height g by H. But i'm not sure how to define the diameter of the rope.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thickness of 1 cm is the diameter of the rope, so there are $280$ turns of the rope.

Comment: i'm feeling so stupid, thanks. That was so obvious.